# JSON.parse error unexpected token u due to value being double?

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, stringify

I am getting unexpected token u attempting to parse something in nodejs with JSON.parse.

I am quite certain I know the issue, but I have tried everything I can think of with no luck at solving it.

Here is the thing I am trying to parse:
{"result": 1.0}
Which seems incredibly weird, because you look at it and think "wait a moment, that doesn't look right". This seems to be a result of my python script(I then send this to the node).

Python:

```
result_dict = {"result": result}
json_str = json.dumps(result_dict, default=lambda x: float(x) if isinstance(x, (float)) else None)
sys.stdout.write(json_str)
```

Nodejs:

```
python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    dataToSend += data.toString();
});

python.on('exit', (code) => {
        if(dataToSend) {

             console.log(dataToSend);
             var result = JSON.parse(dataToSend).result;
     console.log(result);
```

dataToSend logs {"result": 1.0}.
Parsing gives the err of u token though. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: The exact string `{"result": 1.0}` does look like a correct JSON and thus it parsed by `JSON.parse` successfully `Object { result: 1 }` - you can check this in browser's console for instance

Comment: Getting the token u err though

Comment: @Anatoly how did you get Object {result: 1}? Ive tried all I can to get to that point. No idea how though. JSON.parse(dataToSend) gives that U token err.

Comment: Can you add the output of `JSON.stringify(dataToSend)`?